# Using a while loop in python until the list is full

Tags: python

i am trying to add items to a list in Python.
why won't this work?

```
PeoplesNames = [];
while PeoplesNames.len < 3:
    person = input('Enter your name: ')
    PeoplesNames.append(person);
print PeoplesNames
```

surely it uses the len function and once it gets to size 3, it will exit the loop?

Comment: in python you get the length of a list with `len(PeoplesNames)`. and you can drop the `;`.

Comment: You didn't notice the `AttributeError` raised by `PeoplesNames.len`?

Comment: im using this `http://www.skulpt.org/#` and it aint giving me any error advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lists don't have a `len` attribute. You have to call the `len` function with the list as an argument.

```
PeoplesNames = [];
while len(PeoplesNames) < 3:
    person = input('Enter your name: ')
    PeoplesNames.append(person);
print PeoplesNames
```

However, a better solution is to use a list comprehension:

```
peoples_names = [input('Enter your name:') for _ in range(3)]
```

Comment: @cmd I'll borrow the one thing your answer improved on, though: the PEP-8-compliant variable name with the list comprehension.